# Get out-of-fold predictions from xgboost.cv in python

Tags: python, cross-validation, xgboost

In the R xgboost package, I can specify `predictions=TRUE` to save the out-of-fold predictions during cross-validation, e.g.:

```
library(xgboost)
data(mtcars)
xgb_params = list(
  max_depth = 1,
  eta = 0.01
)
x = model.matrix(mpg~0+., mtcars)
train = xgb.DMatrix(x, label=mtcars$mpg)
res = xgb.cv(xgb_params, train, 100, prediction=TRUE, nfold=5)
print(head(res$pred))
```

How would I do the equivalent in the python package?  I can't find a `prediction` argument for `xgboost.cv`in python.

Comment: Right now I'm manually using `sklearn.cross_validation.KFold`, but I'm lazy and if there's a way to do what I want with `xgb.cv` I'd love to do it.

Comment: Sad, that in 2020 xgb.cv is still not supporting that. I find the R library many times better than the Python implementation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can accomplish this by using the sklearn wrapper for xgboost: (I know I'm using iris dataset as regression problem -- which it isn't but this is for illustration).

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_predict as cvp
from sklearn import datasets
X = datasets.load_iris().data[:, :2]
y = datasets.load_iris().target
xgb_model = xgb.XGBRegressor()
y_pred = cvp(xgb_model, X, y, cv=3, n_jobs = 1)
y_pred


array([  9.07209516e-01,   1.84738374e+00,   1.78878939e+00,
         1.83672094e+00,   9.07209516e-01,   9.07209516e-01,
         1.77482617e+00,   9.07209516e-01,   1.75681138e+00,
         1.83672094e+00,   9.07209516e-01,   1.77482617e+00,
         1.84738374e+00,   1.84738374e+00,   1.12216723e+00,
         9.96944368e-01,   9.07209516e-01,   9.07209516e-01,
         9.96944368e-01,   9.07209516e-01,   9.07209516e-01,
         9.07209516e-01,   1.77482617e+00,   8.35850239e-01,
         1.77482617e+00,   9.87186074e-01,   9.07209516e-01,
         9.07209516e-01,   9.07209516e-01,   1.78878939e+00,
         1.83672094e+00,   9.07209516e-01,   9.07209516e-01,
         8.91427517e-01,   1.83672094e+00,   9.09049034e-01,
         8.91427517e-01,   1.83672094e+00,   1.84738374e+00,
         9.07209516e-01,   9.07209516e-01,   1.01038718e+00,
         1.78878939e+00,   9.07209516e-01,   9.07209516e-01,
         1.84738374e+00,   9.07209516e-01,   1.78878939e+00,
         9.07209516e-01,   8.35850239e-01,   1.99947178e+00,
         1.99947178e+00,   1.99947178e+00,   1.94922602e+00,
         1.99975276e+00,   1.91500926e+00,   1.99947178e+00,
         1.97454870e+00,   1.99947178e+00,   1.56287444e+00,
         1.96453893e+00,   1.99947178e+00,   1.99715066e+00,
         1.99947178e+00,   2.84575284e-01,   1.99947178e+00,
         2.84575284e-01,   2.00303388e+00,   1.99715066e+00,
         2.04597521e+00,   1.99947178e+00,   1.99975276e+00,
         2.00527954e+00,   1.99975276e+00,   1.99947178e+00,
         1.99947178e+00,   1.99975276e+00,   1.99947178e+00,
         1.99947178e+00,   1.91500926e+00,   1.95735490e+00,
         1.95735490e+00,   2.00303388e+00,   1.99975276e+00,
         5.92201948e-04,   1.99947178e+00,   1.99947178e+00,
         1.99715066e+00,   2.84575284e-01,   1.95735490e+00,
         1.89267385e+00,   1.99947178e+00,   2.00303388e+00,
         1.96453893e+00,   1.98232651e+00,   2.39597082e-01,
         2.39597082e-01,   1.99947178e+00,   1.97454870e+00,
         1.91500926e+00,   9.99531507e-01,   1.00023842e+00,
         1.00023842e+00,   1.00023842e+00,   1.00023842e+00,
         1.00023842e+00,   9.22234297e-01,   1.00023842e+00,
         1.00100708e+00,   1.16144836e-01,   1.00077248e+00,
         1.00023842e+00,   1.00023842e+00,   1.00100708e+00,
         1.00023842e+00,   1.00077248e+00,   1.00023842e+00,
         1.13711983e-01,   1.00023842e+00,   1.00135887e+00,
         1.00077248e+00,   1.00023842e+00,   1.00023842e+00,
         1.00023842e+00,   9.99531507e-01,   1.00077248e+00,
         1.00023842e+00,   1.00023842e+00,   1.00023842e+00,
         1.00023842e+00,   1.00023842e+00,   1.13711983e-01,
         1.00023842e+00,   1.00023842e+00,   1.00023842e+00,
         1.00023842e+00,   9.78098869e-01,   1.00023842e+00,
         1.00023842e+00,   1.00023842e+00,   1.00023842e+00,
         1.00023842e+00,   1.00023842e+00,   1.00077248e+00,
         9.99531507e-01,   1.00023842e+00,   1.00100708e+00,
         1.00023842e+00,   9.78098869e-01,   1.00023842e+00], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is possible with `xgboost.cv()` but it is a bit hacky. It uses the callbacks and ... a global variable which I'm told is not desirable.

```
def oof_prediction():
    """
    Dirty global variable callback hack.
    """

    global cv_prediction_dict

    def callback(env):
        """internal function"""        
        cv_prediction_list = []

        for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]:
            cv_prediction_list.append([env.cvfolds[i].bst.predict(env.cvfolds[i].dtest)])

        cv_prediction_dict['cv'] = cv_prediction_list

    return callback
```

Now we can call the callback from `xgboost.cv()` as follows.

```
cv_prediction_dict = {}
xgb.cv(xgb_params, train, 100, callbacks=[oof_prediction()]), nfold=5)
pos_oof_predictions = cv_prediction_dict.copy()
```

It will return the out-of-fold prediction for the last iteration/num_boost_round, even if there is `early_stopping` used. I believe this is something the R `predictions=TRUE` functionality [does/did](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1188) not do correctly.

---

*Hack disclaimer: I know this is rather hacky but it is a work around my poor understanding of how the callback is working. If anyone knows how to make this better then please comment.*

Comment: How can I obtain the index of the predicted data?

Comment: @Keiku I think this was one of the problems I had. I am fairly sure that order was maintained by `cv_prediction_list.append(...)` but cannot quite remember now.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I thought that I probably can not get the index. After all, I decided to predict each fold using sklearn.model_selection.KFold.

Comment: Pass the `oof_prediction ` as an argument of a wrapper function. Can have a look at following example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of use a custom `callback` function. This function can also save the best models.

```
import os
def cv_misc_callback(model_dir:str=None, oof_preds:list=None, maximize=True):
    """
    To reduce memory and disk storage, only best models and best oof preds and stored
    For classification, the preds are scores before applying sigmoid.
    """
    state = {}
    def init(env):
        if maximize:
            state['best_score'] = -np.inf
        else:
            state['best_score'] = np.inf
        if (model_dir is not None) and  (not os.path.isdir(model_dir)):
            os.mkdir(model_dir)

        if oof_preds is not None:
            for i, _ in enumerate(env.cvfolds):
                oof_preds.append(None)

    def callback(env):
        if not state:
            init(env)
        best_score = state['best_score']
        score = env.evaluation_result_list[-1][1]
        if (maximize and score > best_score) or (not maximize and score < best_score):
            for i, cvpack in enumerate(env.cvfolds):
                if model_dir is not None:
                    cvpack.bst.save_model(f'{model_dir}/{i}.model')
                if oof_preds is not None:
                    oof_preds[i] = cvpack.bst.predict(cvpack.dtest)
            state['best_score'] = score

    callback.before_iteration = False
    return callback
```

CV code:

```
eval_res = []
oof_preds = []
history = xgb.cv(params, dtrain, num_boost_round=1000,
                 folds=folds, early_stopping_rounds=40, seed=RANDOM_SEED,
                 callbacks=[cv_misc_callback('./models', oof_preds), xgb.callback.print_evaluation(period=10)])
```

Mapping preds list to oof_preds of train_data

```
oof_preds_proba = np.zeros(av_data.shape[0])
for i, (trn_idx, val_idx) in enumerate(folds):
    oof_preds_proba[val_idx] = sigmoid(oof_preds[i])
```

```
@jit
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1 + np.exp(-x))
```