# How do I update an XGBoost callback to the new format?

Tags: python, xgboost

I came across an XGBoost out-of-fold prediction callback in a previous post ([Get out-of-fold predictions from xgboost.cv in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307635/get-out-of-fold-predictions-from-xgboost-cv-in-python)) and shown below. However it does not work because it is not in the new callback format introduced with XGBoost 1.6. I have looked for documation on how to upgrade this callback or understand why it is not in the correct format, but have not found anything useful. Can someone provide how to update this callback or provide me some references to do this?

This is possible with xgboost.cv() but it is a bit hacky. It uses the callbacks and ... a global variable which I'm told is not desirable.

def oof_prediction():
"""
Dirty global variable callback hack.
"""

```
global cv_prediction_dict

def callback(env):
    """internal function"""        
    cv_prediction_list = []

    for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]:
        cv_prediction_list.append([env.cvfolds[i].bst.predict(env.cvfolds[i].dtest)])

    cv_prediction_dict['cv'] = cv_prediction_list

return callback
```

Using this results in the eror below:
ValueError: Old style callback was removed in version 1.6.  See: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/callbacks.html.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I guess you have to define your callback as a class that inherits "TrainingCallback" as described here in the
[xgboost custom callbacks documentation.](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/examples/callbacks.html#sphx-glr-python-examples-callbacks-py)